# Solr unable to create core caused by write.lock

Tags: indexing, solr

I'm getting an error:
rror CREATEing SolrCore 'shopping_items': Unable to create core [shopping_items] Caused by: /solr-8.4.1/server/solr/shopping_items/data/index/write.lock

This happens after I shut down the solr server and restart (that specific core disappeared so I try to create it back)

I already removed the write.lock file and restart solr but it still says it's here. I also ls -l to see if there are any hidden files and I confirm that write.lock is not here.

Any solutions?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17444493/caused-by-org-apache-solr-common-solrexception-index-locked-for-write-for-core

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Voting to close as duplicate: [Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Index locked for write for core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17444493/caused-by-org-apache-solr-common-solrexception-index-locked-for-write-for-core)